# Format a number to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

Give me a native (no jQuery, Prototype, etc. please) JavaScript function that converts numbers as follows:

```
input:  0.39, 2.5,  4.25, 5.5,  6.75, 7.75, 8.5
output: 0.39, 2.50, 4.25, 5.50, 6.75, 7.75, 8.50
```

E.g., in Ruby, I'd do something like this:

```
>> sprintf("%.2f", 2.5)
=> "2.50"
```

The output may be a number or a string. I don't really care because I'm just using it to set `innerHTML`.

Thank you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, sorry for not responding to your comment. Thank you for pointing that out and for asking me to clarify. I don't remember what I wanted, but let's just say `5.52` because that's what [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) seems to return, and I accepted that as the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, . If only Stack Overflow had a badge for that. (It's all good.) Thanks! You too, happy coding! :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134039/242933)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
input = 0.3;
output = input.toFixed(2);
// output: 0.30
```

A newer option, which supports rounding:

```js
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}).format(1.005)
// Outputs: 1.01
```

Comment: It does not work with 1.005 or 2.005, they round incorrectly. (1.005).toFixed(2) == '1.00' and (2.005).toFixed(2) == '2.00'. Should be '1.01' and '2.01', respectively.

Comment: Thanks for updating. In fact, I have used the Intl.NumberFormat function in my use case, too. It takes care for default rounding and you can alternatively pick from a myriad of other rounding methods.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method on [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) objects:

```
var array = [0.39, 2.5,  4.25, 5.5,  6.75, 7.75, 8.5], new_array = [];
for(var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
    if(typeof array[i] !== 'number') continue;
    new_array.push(array[i].toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `toFixed` with 2 as the number of decimal places.

Comment: It does not work with 1.005 or 2.005, they round incorrectly. (1.005).toFixed(2) == '1.00' and (2.005).toFixed(2) == '2.00'. Should be '1.01' and '2.01', respectively.

Comment: The OP didn't mention rounding at all; rounding is not always the desired outcome, and there are multiple rounding styles as well.

Comment: The OP didn't mention rounding directly, but indirectly by writing 'E.g., in Ruby, I'd do something like this: >> sprintf("%.2f", 2.5)'. In Ruby, the sprintf function does by default round numbers similar to the round function.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `Intl.NumberFormat()` with `{ style: 'percent'}`

```js
var num = 25;

var option = {
  style: 'percent'

};
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", option);
var percentFormat = formatter.format(num / 100);
console.log(percentFormat);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Except your code doesn't work exactly for the inputs & outputs in the body of my question. I just edited the title of my question to better match its body. This way answers my question: `console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(2.5))`.