# Format number to always show 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, floating-point, number-formatting

I would like to format my numbers to always display 2 decimal places, rounding where applicable.

Examples:

```
number     display
------     -------
1          1.00
1.341      1.34
1.345      1.35
```

I have been using this:

```
parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
```

But it's displaying `1` as `1`, rather than `1.00`.

Comment: I mean if I enter 1 it will not show the number as 1.00, But if I enter 1.345 then it will show 1.35

Comment: I've reworded your question to what I believe you were looking for. Please check to make sure I've understood you correctly.

Comment: precise rounding  with ie support . https://gist.github.com/ArminVieweg/28647e735aa6efaba401

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, what's the best way of formatting a number to 2 decimal places?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477892/in-jquery-whats-the-best-way-of-formatting-a-number-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting a number with exactly two decimals in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726630/formatting-a-number-with-exactly-two-decimals-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a number to two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4610298/242933)

Comment: ```const numA =1;
const numB = parseFloat(numA).toFixed(2);
console.log(numA); // #=> 1
console.log(numB); // #=> "1.00"```
the question is invalid.

Answer (score 1733, accepted):

```
(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

**Live Demo**

```js
var num1 = "1";
document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = (Math.round(num1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

var num2 = "1.341";
document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = (Math.round(num2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

var num3 = "1.345";
document.getElementById('num3').innerHTML = (Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="num1"></span>
<span id="num2"></span>
<span id="num3"></span>
```

Note that it will **round** to 2 decimal places, so the input `1.346` will return `1.35`.

Comment: It should work in ALL browsers which is why I think OP did not tell us the real issue.

Comment: @OP this doesn't work according the your question, does it? It shows 1.34. You wanted to preserve 1.341, whilst being able to display 1 as 1.00, didn't you? Not that I mind much, but it's strange that you have chosen this answer as being the right one.

Comment: @Kooilnc: OP wants `1` to display as `1.00`, and `1.341` to display as `1.34`.

Comment: No need to use round() since toFixed() rounds it.

Comment: Use this method for precise rounding : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25075575/781695

Comment: toFixed() does round it but don't forget it's returning a string...So this method is really only useful for display.  If you want to perform further mathematical computations on the rounded value do not use toFixed().

Comment: according to MDN, Math.round will not always give accurate results due to rounding errors.  I tested this with 1.005, which should round to 1.01, but it gives 1.00.  Use my answer for consistent accuracy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34796988/3549440.

Comment: @TWright Yes, this returns a string. You could easily wrap the entire code in another parseFloat which will change it back to a number.

Comment: This entire answer could be reduced to `(+num).toFixed(2)`. It even retains the rounding bug in the original, see [*Nate's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places/34796988#34796988).

Comment: Why are you doing Math.round and parseFloat?? 
toFixed() alone is enough to achieve the required result.

Comment: @stealthysnacks 2 will be converted to integer. But we need a decimal.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov not in all cases, suppose you have 4.485 gives you 4.48 but this method gives 4.49 which is correct. You may try.

Comment: Do we really need the `parseFloat()`?

Comment: This does not work `parseFloat(Math.round(-3.4028230607370965e+38 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);` returns `"-3.4028230607370965e+38"` instead of `0.00`

Comment: `code` function numberWithCommas(number) { 

    var newval = parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

    return newval.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

Comment: I got 00 after this but toFixed only work. Its not working or I am missing something.

Comment: To clarify on the rounding rules.  If you are rounding "5", it rounds to the nearest even number. 3.5 to 4.5 would round to 4, for example.  This means that rounding 4.485 SHOULD give you 4.48 and not 4.49 - 5 is weird like that, I guess because if you ALWAYS rounded up, rounding a large set of numbers would be much more inaccurate than if half the 5s went up and half went down.

Comment: i've been largely inactive here for about a decade, and it still blows my mind when i see weekly points coming from this answer.

Comment: my number is `0.434496` and the result I want is `0.44` how can I do it? Considering till last decimal place is 0.000006

Answer (score 487):

```
Number(1).toFixed(2);         // 1.00
Number(1.341).toFixed(2);     // 1.34
Number(1.345).toFixed(2);     // 1.34 NOTE: See andy's comment below.
Number(1.3450001).toFixed(2); // 1.35
```

```js
document.getElementById('line1').innerHTML = Number(1).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('line2').innerHTML = Number(1.341).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('line3').innerHTML = Number(1.345).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('line4').innerHTML = Number(1.3450001).toFixed(2);
```

```html
<span id="line1"></span>
<br/>
<span id="line2"></span>
<br/>
<span id="line3"></span>
<br/>
<span id="line4"></span>
```

Comment: @Andre, Chrome 29.0.1547.57 gives me `1.34` for expression `Number(1.345).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: toFixed *does* do rounding, which you can see on almost every test number.

Comment: Accidentally submitted that last comment before finishing.. `1.345` is an example of a number that can't be stored exactly in floating point, so I think the reason that it doesn't round as you expect, is that it's actually stored as a number slightly less than 1.345 and it rounds down. If you test instead with `(1.34500001).toFixed(2)` then you see it correctly rounds up to `1.35`

Comment: Way late, but to shed some light on the "5" rounding, it always rounds to the nearest even number.  1.345 would round to 1.34, but so would 1.335.  Half the time 5 goes up and half the time 5 goes down.

Comment: @Bardicer, 1.335 rounds to 1.33 using toFixed(2)

Answer (score 160):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134070) will fail if `value = 1.005`.

As a better solution, the rounding problem can be avoided by using numbers represented in exponential notation:

```
Number(Math.round(1.005+'e2')+'e-2'); // 1.01
```

Cleaner code as suggested by @Kon, and the original author:

```
Number(Math.round(parseFloat(value + 'e' + decimalPlaces)) + 'e-' + decimalPlaces)
```

You may add `toFixed()` at the end to retain the decimal point e.g: `1.00` but note that it will return as string.

```
Number(Math.round(parseFloat(value + 'e' + decimalPlaces)) + 'e-' + decimalPlaces).toFixed(decimalPlaces)
```

Credit: [Rounding Decimals in JavaScript](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/)

Comment: Amazingly, everyone else in here failed to see that `toFixed` has that rounding problem. Your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: Just tested to see if this was still the case. you are still correct for Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 Your solution will round up for 1.005 (1.01) and round down for 1.00499999 (1.00)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Artistan/qq895bnp/28/  there are "times" when toFixed will work, but it is quite inconsistent. :)

Comment: surround Number in parseFloat is its returning string

Comment: This is a solid answer. A couple of improvements I can think of: (1) VS Code (TypeScript file) doesn't like Math.round() passing in a string. (2) Make number of decimal places dynamic (not hard-coded to 2). (3) toFixed() seems unnecessary. So what I came up with is `Number(Math.round(parseFloat(value + 'e' + decimalPlaces)) + 'e-' + decimalPlaces)`

Comment: If you remove `toFixed` you lose the number of decimals. I.e: 0.000 is displayed as 0.

Comment: When rounding 5, you round to the nearest even number.

Comment: VS code doesn't accept the round function with e in it. alternatively, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/53378133/3485836 , both are returning correct o/p

Comment: hi, just passing through.  if performance is a concern, please think twice before using string parsing as part of a Number-to-String routine.

Answer (score 118):

For modern browsers, use [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```javascript
var num = 1.345;
num.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

Specify a locale tag as first parameter to control the [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator). For a dot, use for example English U.S. locale:

```
num.toLocaleString("en-US", { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

which gives:

> 1.35

Most countries in Europe use a comma as decimal separator, so if you for example use Swedish/Sweden locale:

```
num.toLocaleString("sv-SE", { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

it will give:

> 1,35

Answer (score 43):

I would suggest you use

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(num)
```

that way you will also have the local format of a country you specify, plus it would garantee to show exact 2 decimals (whether when num is 1 or 1.12345, it will show 1.00 and 1.12 respectively)

In this example I used German localization, because I wanted my numbers show with thousands delimiter, so this would be some outputs:

```
1 => 1,00
1.12 => 1,12
1.1234 => 1,12
1234 => 1.234,00
1234.1234 => 1.234,12
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you. As a side note: this English version of this uses: 'en-US' instead of 'de-DE'

Answer (score 36):

```js
var num = new Number(14.12);
console.log(num.toPrecision(2)); //outputs 14
console.log(num.toPrecision(3)); //outputs 14.1
console.log(num.toPrecision(4)); //outputs 14.12
console.log(num.toPrecision(5)); //outputs 14.120
```

Comment: That gives unexpected results, if your number can be 1.4, and 23.654, and 0, what precision would you take?

Comment: Note the OP is asking for **"rounding where applicable"**. `toPrecision` only formats the number to a specific number of decimal places, simply leaving out redundant places, but **not rounding them**. This could be very useful too of course, but it's important to understand the difference.

Comment: Actually [toPrecision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) does round, according to Mozilla. Test: `(20.55).toPrecision(3) 
"20.6"`

Comment: If you want to [strip trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612744/remove-insignificant-trailing-zeros-from-a-number), cast it to a Number or Float after using `toFixed`: `const formattedVal = Number(val.toFixed(2));` Do not use `toPrecision`, as it counts the non-decimal numbers when using the precision param.

Answer (score 32):

For the most accurate rounding, create this function and use it to round to 2 decimal places:

```js
function round(value, decimals) {
  return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals).toFixed(decimals);
}



console.log("seeked to " + round(1.005, 2));
```

```
> 1.01
```

Thanks to [Razu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178833/3549440), [this](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/) article, and [MDN's Math.round reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Comment: what about 1.0049999999999998934 ?

Comment: It does not go beyond 2 d.p

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Artistan/qq895bnp/ tested, this is the only consistent method I have seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

```js
var number = 123456.789;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}).format(number));
```

Comment: If you want it to always show 2 decimal places, even for whole numbers, then the option to use is ```minimumFractionDigits``` not maximum.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat#minimumfractiondigits

Answer (score 15):

You are not giving us the whole picture.

`javascript:alert(parseFloat(1).toFixed(2))` shows 1.00 in my browsers when I paste it into the location bar.
However if you do something to it afterwards, it will revert.

```js
alert(parseFloat(1).toFixed(2))

var num = 2
document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML = (parseFloat(num).toFixed(2) - 1)
```

```html
<span id="spanId"></span>
```

```
shows 1 and not 1.00
```

Comment: Works in FF 50, Chrome 49 and IE 8

Answer (score 14):

Simplest answer:

```
var num = 1.2353453;
num.toFixed(2); // 1.24
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/E2XU7/

Comment: Well, `toFixed` was already suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/13292833/218196. What additional information does your question provide?

Comment: that answer does not include round functionality, my answer includes tho.

Comment: Uh? It's exactly the same answer. Calling `toFixed` on a number.

Comment: Correct, same function, but the result of that answer is misleading, I just rectified it by expressing the round functionality.

Comment: The question states : "...rounding where applicable". Your answer does not involve rounding.

Comment: His answer demonstrates that `toFixed` does do rounding.

Answer (score 14):

Good news!!!!!
It seems that the new version of javascript, ES2020 (I'm using just), provided new behavior of this function.

```
let ff:number =3
console.info(ff.toFixed(2)) //3.00
```

as desired.

Answer (score 13):

Are you looking for floor?

```js
var num = 1.42482;
var num2 = 1;
var fnum = Math.floor(num).toFixed(2);
var fnum2 = Math.floor(num2).toFixed(2);
console.log(fnum + " and " + fnum2); //both values will be 1.00
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to round down to the nearest integer.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't sure from the description, but I was just throwing it out there incase

Answer (score 13):

A much more generic solution for rounding to N places

```
function roundN(num,n){
  return parseFloat(Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, n)) /Math.pow(10,n)).toFixed(n);
}


console.log(roundN(1,2))
console.log(roundN(1.34,2))
console.log(roundN(1.35,2))
console.log(roundN(1.344,2))
console.log(roundN(1.345,2))
console.log(roundN(1.344,3))
console.log(roundN(1.345,3))
console.log(roundN(1.3444,3))
console.log(roundN(1.3455,3))

Output

1.00
1.34
1.35
1.34
1.35
1.344
1.345
1.344
1.346
```

Comment: This alswer fails with certain numbers close to 0, `roundN(-3.4028230607370965e+38,2)` returns `"-3.4028230607370965e+38"` instead of the expected 0.00

Comment: interesting @Ferrybig i ll test the numbers you mentioned and think of a workaround, thanks for testing

Comment: Note that the before mentioned number should not show zero, but a huge number instead, this was just an error in my brain. But it still doesn't work, since it still doesn't show 2 decimals

Answer (score 10):

If you're already using jQuery, you could look at using the [jQuery Number Format](https://www.customd.com/articles/14/jquery-number-format-redux) plugin.

The plugin can return formatted numbers as a string, you can set decimal, and thousands separators, and you can choose the number of decimals to show.

```
$.number( 123, 2 ); // Returns '123.00'
```

You can also get [jQuery Number Format from GitHub](http://github.com/teamdf/jquery-number/).

Comment: It is overkill to use a plugin "just to have fixed length decimal part".

Comment: @Lashae, sure, if thats all you want to do. I posted this in case the OP or anyone else wanted the extra functionality that the plugin provides as well.

Comment: if the poster of the question had added the jQuery tag of course ;)

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you mean?

[**edit 20200530**] The answer [@razu provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places/32178833#32178833) is the best imho. So here's a slightly refactored version.

The snippet code will still not return the right value for something like `showAsFloat(2.3346)` (result 2.33, but should be 2.34). So, [see also](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mmrre8?file=index.ts).

```js
const showAsFloat = (input, decimals = 2, asString = false) => {
  if (input === null || input.constructor === Boolean || isNaN(+input)) {
    return input;
  }
  const converted = +( `${Math.round( parseFloat( `${input}e${decimals}` )  )}e-${decimals}` );
  return asString ? converted.toFixed(decimals) : converted
};

document.querySelector('#result').textContent = [
  'command                      | result',
  '-----------------------------------------------',
  'showAsFloat(1);              | ' + showAsFloat(1),
  'showAsFloat(1.314);          | ' + showAsFloat(1.314),
  'showAsFloat(\'notanumber\')    | ' + showAsFloat('notanumber'),
  'showAsFloat(\'23.44567\', 3)   | ' + showAsFloat('23.44567', 3),
  'showAsFloat(2456198, 5, true)| ' + showAsFloat('24568', 5, true),
  'showAsFloat(2456198, 5)      | ' + showAsFloat('24568', 5),
  'showAsFloat(0, 2, true);     | ' + showAsFloat(0, 2, true),
  'showAsFloat(1.345);          | ' + showAsFloat(1.345),
  'showAsFloat(0.005);          | ' + showAsFloat(0.005),
  'showAsFloat(null);           | ' + showAsFloat(null),

].join('\n');
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Note that this solution will fail to round correctly in certain cases: `1.005` comes out to `1.00`, and `1.345` as `1.34`.

Comment: That's why @razu's answer should be the accepted one ...

Answer (score 6):

Convert a number into a string, keeping only two decimals:

```
var num = 5.56789;
var n = num.toFixed(2);
```

The result of n will be:

```
5.57
```

Answer (score 6):

Just run into this one of longest thread, below is my solution:

```
parseFloat(Math.round((parseFloat(num * 100)).toFixed(2)) / 100 ).toFixed(2)
```

Let me know if anyone can poke a hole

Answer (score 4):

```
function currencyFormat (num) {
    return "$" + num.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
}

console.info(currencyFormat(2665));   // $2,665.00
console.info(currencyFormat(102665)); // $102,665.00
```

Answer (score 3):

Where specific formatting is required, you should write your own routine or use a library function that does what you need. The basic ECMAScript functionality is usually insufficient for displaying formatted numbers.

<strike>A thorough explanation of rounding and formatting is here: http://www.merlyn.demon.co.uk/js-round.htm#RiJ</strike>

As a general rule, rounding and formatting should only be peformed as a last step before output. Doing so earlier may introduce unexpectedly large errors and destroy the formatting.

Comment: There are times when I shake my head at my own choice to get so deeply involved of late in this whole JS/Ecma platform. :(

"Where specific formatting is required, you should write your own routine or use a library function that does what you need. The basic ECMAScript functionality is usually insufficient for displaying formatted numbers."

What an asinine statement - not that you made it, but because that fact exists. Just sad. Get on the ball, Javascript! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's also a generic function that can format to any number of decimal places:

```
function numberFormat(val, decimalPlaces) {

    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, decimalPlaces);
    return (Math.round(val * multiplier) / multiplier).toFixed(decimalPlaces);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

here is another solution to round only using floor, meaning, making sure calculated amount won't be bigger than the original amount (sometimes needed for transactions):

```
Math.floor(num* 100 )/100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function number_format(string,decimals=2,decimal=',',thousands='.',pre='R$ ',pos=' Reais'){
  var numbers = string.toString().match(/\d+/g).join([]);
  numbers = numbers.padStart(decimals+1, "0");
  var splitNumbers = numbers.split("").reverse();
  var mask = '';
  splitNumbers.forEach(function(d,i){
    if (i == decimals) { mask = decimal + mask; }
    if (i>(decimals+1) && ((i-2)%(decimals+1))==0) { mask = thousands + mask; }
    mask = d + mask;
  });
  return pre + mask + pos;
}
var element = document.getElementById("format");
var money= number_format("10987654321",2,',','.');
element.innerHTML = money;
```

```css
#format{
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
border:1px solid #ddd;
background:#f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id='format'>Test 123456789</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
function numberWithCommas(number) { 

   var newval = parseFloat(Math.round(number * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

   return newval.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var quantity = 12;

var import1 = 12.55;

var total = quantity * import1;

var answer = parseFloat(total).toFixed(2);

document.write(answer);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to decide between the parseFloat() and Number() conversions before I could make toFixed() call. Here's an example of a number formatting post-capturing user input.

HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="dec-number" min="0" step="0.01" />
```

Event handler:

```
$('.dec-number').on('change', function () {
     const value = $(this).val();
     $(this).val(value.toFixed(2));
});
```

The above code will result in TypeError exception. Note that although the html input type is "number", the user input is actually a "string" data type. However, toFixed() function may only be invoked on an object that is a Number.

My final code would look as follows:

```
$('.dec-number').on('change', function () {
     const value = Number($(this).val());
     $(this).val(value.toFixed(2));
});
```

The reason I favor to cast with Number() vs. parseFloat() is because I don't have to perform an extra validation neither for an empty input string, nor NaN value. The Number() function would automatically handle an empty string and covert it to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var num1 = "0.1";
document.getElementById('num1').innerHTML = (Math.round(num1 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

var num2 = "1.341";
document.getElementById('num2').innerHTML = (Math.round(num2 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

var num3 = "1.345";
document.getElementById('num3').innerHTML = (Math.round(num3 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="num1"></span>
<span id="num2"></span>
<span id="num3"></span>
```

Comment: This piece of code is enough to achieve your requirement

`parseFloat(num.toFixed(2))`

Answer (score 1):

## RegExp - alternative approach

On input you have string (because you use parse) so we can get result by using only string manipulations and integer number calculations

```js
let toFix2 = (n) => n.replace(/(-?)(\d+)\.(\d\d)(\d+)/, (_,s,i,d,r)=> {
  let k= (+r[0]>=5)+ +d - (r==5 && s=='-');
  return s + (+i+(k>99)) + "." + ((k>99)?"00":(k>9?k:"0"+k));
})


// TESTs

console.log(toFix2("1"));
console.log(toFix2("1.341"));
console.log(toFix2("1.345"));
console.log(toFix2("1.005"));
```

Explanation

- `s` is sign, `i` is integer part, `d` are first two digits after dot, `r` are other digits (we use `r[0]` value to calc rounding)
- `k` contains information about last two digits (represented as integer number)
- if `r[0]` is `>=5` then we add `1` to `d` - but in case when we have minus number (`s=='-'`) and `r` is exact equal to 5 then in this case we substract 1 (for compatibility reasons - in same way `Math.round` works for minus numbers e.g `Math.round(-1.5)==-1`)
- after that if last two digits `k` are greater than 99 then we add one to integer part `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/).

```
numeral(1.341).format('0.00') // 1.34
numeral(1.345).format('0.00') // 1.35
```

Answer (score 0):

I do like:

```
var num = 12.749;
parseFloat((Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)); // 123.75
```

Round the number with 2 decimal points,
then make sure to parse it with `parseFloat()` 
to return Number, not String unless you don't care if it is String or Number.

Comment: I guess if the purpose was to display with 2 decimals precision, parsing the float will mess with that. E.g. `parseFloat("1.00") // 1`

Answer (score 0):

Extend **Math** object with **precision** method

```js
Object.defineProperty(Math, 'precision',{
   value: function (value,precision,type){
             var v = parseFloat(value),
                 p = Math.max(precision,0)||0,
                 t = type||'round';
              return (Math[t](v*Math.pow(10,p))/Math.pow(10,p)).toFixed(p);
          }
    });

console.log(
    Math.precision(3.1,3), // round 3 digits 
    Math.precision(0.12345,2,'ceil'), // ceil 2 digits
    Math.precision(1.1) // integer part
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are handled differntly in a way using JavaScript, be careful with round(), toFixed(), etc. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
export const preciseRound = (value, exp) => {
  /**
   * Decimal adjustment of a number.
   *
   * @param   {String}    type    The type of adjustment.
   * @param   {Number}    value   The number.
   * @param   {Integer}   exp     The exponent (the 10 logarithm of the adjustment base).
   * @returns {Number}            The adjusted value.
   */
  function decimalAdjust(type, value, exp) {
    // If the exp is undefined or zero...
    if (typeof exp === "undefined" || +exp === 0) {
      return Math[type](value);
    }
    value = +value;
    exp = +exp;
    // If the value is not a number or the exp is not an integer...
    if (isNaN(value) || !(typeof exp === "number" && exp % 1 === 0)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    // Shift
    value = value.toString().split("e");
    value = Math[type](+(value[0] + "e" + (value[1] ? +value[1] - exp : -exp)));
    // Shift back
    value = value.toString().split("e");
    return +(value[0] + "e" + (value[1] ? +value[1] + exp : exp));
  }

  // You can use floor, ceil or round
  return decimalAdjust("round", value, exp);
};
```

```
console.log(preciseRound(1.005, -2));  // <= 1.01
console.log(preciseRound(1.341, -2));  // <= 1.34
console.log(preciseRound(1.01, -2));   // <= 1.01
console.log(preciseRound(33.355, -2)); // <= 33.36
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to decimal 2 digits, without adding 1 if decimal third digit is >= 5.

```
var num = 5482.658684;
let n = (Math.floor((num) * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(n);
```

Output of 5482.658684 is = 5482.65;

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js" integrity="sha512-pHVGpX7F/27yZ0ISY+VVjyULApbDlD0/X0rgGbTqCE7WFW5MezNTWG/dnhtbBuICzsd0WQPgpE4REBLv+UqChw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<input type="text" class = 'item_price' name="price" min="1.00" placeholder="Enter Price" value="{{ old('price') }}" step="">

<script> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item_price').mask('00000.00', { reverse: true });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to include two gigantic, unecessary browser-only libraries, respond to DOM events, and manipulate the DOM in order to format a number. You should read through some of the other answers before posting.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my safe solution which uses epsilion. This will fix rounding with .15 e.g

```
function myFunction(a) {

    return Math.round((a + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
    function FormatNumber(number, numberOfDigits = 2) {
        try {
            return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(parseFloat(number).toFixed(numberOfDigits));
        } catch (error) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    var test1 = FormatNumber('1000000.4444');
    alert(test1); // 1,000,000.44

    var test2 = FormatNumber(100000000000.55555555, 4);
    alert(test2); // 100,000,000,000.5556
```

Comment: You better change the toFixed(2) to toFixed(numberOfDigits) :D

Answer (score -2):

```
function formatValeurDecimal(valeurAFormate,longueurPartieEntier,longueurPartieDecimal){

valeurAFormate = valeurAFormate.replace(",",".")
valeurAFormate = parseFloat(valeurAFormate).toFixed(longueurPartieDecimal)
if(valeurAFormate == 'NaN'){
    return 0
}

//____________________valeurPartieEntier__________________________________
var valeurPartieEntier = valeurAFormate | 0

var strValeur = valeurPartieEntier.toString()
strValeur = strValeur.substring(0, longueurPartieEntier)
valeurPartieEntier = strValeur

//____________________valeurPartieDecimal__________________________________
strValeur = valeurAFormate
strValeur = strValeur.substring(strValeur.indexOf('.')+1)
var valeurPartieDecimal = strValeur

valeurAFormate = valeurPartieEntier +'.'+valeurPartieDecimal
if(valeurAFormate == null){
    valeurAFormate = 0
}

return valeurAFormate
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Besides a missing explanation the code uses French variable names.

Answer (score -3):

```
(num + "").replace(/^([0-9]*)(\.[0-9]{1,2})?.*$/,"$1$2")
```

Answer (score -3):

This is how I solve my problem:

```
parseFloat(parseFloat(floatString).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score -3):

`parseInt(number * 100) / 100;` worked for me.