# Rounding a number to exactly two decimal places for currency formatting

Tags: javascript, currency, rounding

I need to round to two decimal places for currency.

Both

```
Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2)
```

and

```
Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2)
```

work except it cuts any trailing zero's off so I get `29.9` instead of `29.90`.

What is the best way around this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 29):

You can add this to number which you want to set specific format

```
.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: `toFixed(2)` is not good for currency formatting since it sometimes rounds half up and sometimes half down. For example `(0.615).toFixed(2)` gives `0.61` (half down) while `(0.625)` gives `0.63` (half up).

Comment: For currency, Vytalyi's answer doesn't work property, to the examples that Luksaz stated.

Comment: @Vytalyi answer is absolutely fine.  .toFixed follows rounding principles as stated in Mathematics and as it should. If an odd number prefixes the number 5 then truncation happens else it rounds up.

Comment: Yikes, `(0.615).toFixed(2)` is a weird **wrong** with returning `0.61` case. While `(0.515).toFixed(2)` works fine with returning the correct `0.52`.

Comment: @kaiser, it uses banker's rounding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score 10):

```
(Math.round(num*Math.pow(10,2))/Math.pow(10,2)).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using this, seems to be ok

```js
Math.round(x * 100)/100
```

Its look like shortest

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to think about it as a total amount of cents. 19.999 = 1999.9 cents, the 3rd decimal does not matter you cant pay it anyway.

This makes sense:

```
function convertToMoney(val){
    return (Math.floor(val*100).toFixed(0)/100).toFixed(2);
}
```