# How to round prices using rounding rules for Croatia - jQuery round down

Tags: jquery

I am getting frustrated. All examples I can find lack basic math.

My problem: I need to round these values to 2 decimal places:

```
1,235 = 1,23
1,236 = 1,24
1,234 = 1,23
```

I tried

```
var num = 1,235;
Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
num.toFixed(2);
Math.round(num +'e2')+'e-2');
```

all fail in one of the cases.

Solutions world wide suggest that 1,235 should be rounded up to 1,24, but in our country, government said that it needs to round down to 1,23 - and here lies the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding a number to exactly two decimal places for currency formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402273/rounding-a-number-to-exactly-two-decimal-places-for-currency-formatting)

Comment: No. It seams that in whole world 1.235 = 1.24 except in Croatia. Here government said it needs to be rounded down. I don't know if I am crazy or???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inner workings of `.round()`

The usual rounding we know rounds from `0.5` onwards to the next whole number.

What round does under the hood is almost what you wanted to implement. However the key is using `.floor()`.

Imagine a number 6.5. We want it rounded to 7. If you didn't have `round()` as a function how would you do that by hand?
Well, like this:

```js
Math.floor(6.5 + 0.5);
```

So naturally this results in 7.0. A value like 6.1 would remain a 6. Good that's how we want that to work. So adding the cutoff-point where we want to round up and flooring the value means we get the rounded number.

We can now also do that with decimal places like you discovered. See example below.

### Implement your own rounding

In your case, you want to do that with a decimal place. You were correct in multiplying by 100. But then you must apply the rounding example from above and use `0.4` instead of `0.5`.

So you can just implement your own rounding. The code below will round from `x.006` onward to the next unit.

```js
// rounded: 1,23   1,23   1,24
var arr = [ 1.234, 1.235, 1.236 ];
arr.forEach((num) => {
  var rounded = Math.floor((num * 100.0) + .4) / 100.0;
  console.log( 'Result=', rounded, 'toFixed(2)=', rounded.toFixed(2), 'Original=', num);
});
```

Comment: What a wonderful and in depth answer. Thank you from bottom of my heart!

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome! I would suggest you change your question's title to say *"How to round prices using rounding rules for Croatia"*. It is more clear what you were asking and also help others find this solution when internet searching.