# Need present whole number with 2 decimals (5.00) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this

```
Math.round((Math.abs(21600 / 3600))*100)/100
>> 6 # want 6.00
Math.round((Math.abs(21000 / 3600))*100)/100
>> 5.83 # This is right
```

I need 2 decimals on whole number.

Comment: Great! 5 answers in 3 minutes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Alnitak's answer makes this a good conversation. His answer also cleans up the code considerably!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), but there's no need to manually round the value to the nearest 0.01 first - the `.toFixed` function will do that for you.

```
var str = Math.abs(21600 / 3600).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: all votes gratefully accepted - I'm trying to hit 100k rep today ;-)

Comment: toFixed() won't result in a number, but rather a string

Comment: @Confused indeed, and that's why my variable is named `str`.  Rounding floating point numbers is invariably a _presentation_ problem, not a math one.

Comment: I've been struggling with this exact topic all day. Maybe it's just my ocd but I can't stand that it's so hard to maintain a #.0 in js!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```
(Math.round((Math.abs(21600 / 3600))*100)/100).toFixed( 2 );
```

Comment: This is overkill - `(21600/3600).toFixed(2)` is sufficient

Comment: @Dennis true, however its totally irrelevant for the question.

Comment: It's totally relevant.  OP was trying to multiply/round/divide to trim the number - `toFixed` handles this so it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Dennis http://beta.bucketlamp.com/upload/2009/09/16/1253083798_display_1253083798cat_watermelon.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(Math.round((Math.abs(21600 / 3600))*100)/100).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) method:

```
var num = num.toFixed(6);
```

Now num wil be equal to 6.00

Comment: what does that DOM stuff add to this answer?  The OP might not even be using a browser.