# JavaScript decimal numbers

Tags: javascript

So I made this quick script that calculates some numbers, but the answer ends with many decimal numbers. How do I make it so it only shows 2 numbers after the "."?

```
Function test() {
var g1 = document.testino.v1.value * 10 / 5 + 38;
var g2 = document.testino.v2.value / 2046 * 9;
var g3 = g1 + g2;
document.testino.uitkomst.value= g3;
parseFloat_num.toFixed(2);
```

This is what i have now but it still doesn't work.
Please don't hate I am just learning and I rather aks then search all over google or wherever.

Comment: You forgot to paste the code.

Comment: You should've searched for it atleast once on google.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method:

```
number.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I know that it souns stupid but where exactly do i add this?

Comment: @WouterSanders I can't tell you for sure, since we still don't see your code.

Comment: edited the post to show the code. forgot to add it my bad.

Comment: @WouterSanders OK. So based on your code, you need to apply it to `g3` variable when you try to display the value, i.e. `document.testino.uitkomst.value = g3.toFixed(2);`.

Comment: Thank you this worked. If im right it will keep on going until it reaches the number I inserted right?

stupid question ofcourse it does (facepalm)

Comment: @WouterSanders Sorry, I didn't get what you ask me.

Comment: Doesn't quite matter it was a stupid question anyway and I've got the answer myself. But the question basicly was if i change the 2 in g3.toFixed(2);, it will keep on going until the number I change it to, like if I make the number 3 it will show 3 numbers.

Comment: @WouterSanders Yes, that's exactly how it works: rounds up the decimal part of number up to given `N` numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you mind helping me with one more question? So now when I enter the numbers 1 and 1 the answer will be 40, but with the toFixed it will be 40.00. Is there a way to make that just end at 40?

Comment: @WouterSanders Try to convert the derived string to number with `+g3.toFixed(2)`.

Comment: I am using the toFixed method at the moment. And it works but I would like to get into this a little deeper. So as asked in my last question. Is there a way to make answers like 40.00 show as just 40, while still using a method like this?

Comment: @WouterSanders As I answered in my last answer, you may convert string to a number with `+` before the statement (pay attention to `+` sign before `g3.toFixed(2)`).

Comment: Oops my bad again. Completely misunderstood you there. Thanks for your time to help me!