# How can i round a number to 2 decimal places(compelsory) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to round a number to 2 decimal places .
i am showing with an example

```
var k =10.3;
alert(parseFloat(k),2); // outputs 10.3
alert(Math.round(k).toFixed(2)); // outputs 10.00
```

the result i need is **10.30**
what is the solution for this .

please help

thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=How+can+i+round+a+number+to+2+decimal+places(compelsory)+in+javascript This already shows you quite a lot of good answers to your question.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var k = 10.3;
k.toFixed(2);  // 10.30
```

Answer (score 2):

To format a number using fixed-point notation, you can simply use the toFixed method:

```
(10.8).toFixed(2); // 10.80

var num = 2.4;
alert(num.toFixed(2)); // 2.40
```