# Show 0 value in floating point values, for currency

Tags: javascript, floating-point

How can I make a flaoting point number always have two decimal places, even when one is a zero?

E.g `var postageCost = 3.2` but I want to display it as `3.20` - is this something that must be added as a string or is it possible to actually change the number?

Comment: Floating point numbers don't have any fixed number of decimal places. This is about how you render them for human consumption.

Answer (score 0):

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places), you can use

```
parseFloat(Math.round(postageCost * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```