# Want to add .00 to order total

Tags: javascript

In javascript I'm multiplying the price of item and quantity to display its total.
For example: the item price be 48.00 and quantity is 3. If I multiply them in javascript, I'm getting the value like 144. But, I want as 144.00

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Comment: Try with this... `(48.00*3).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Rakesh_Kumar comment is correct.

Comment: Some searching and you could of found something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
var nr = 48.00 * 3;
alert( nr.toFixed(2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library I have been using for some time

http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format/

It is a reproduction of the php number_format into js