# Select number then format to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some code that will do the following;

1. Add an ID to nth child
2. Format the number in nth child to 2 decimal places
3. Apply £ in front of the numbers
4. Loop until every nth child in a table is done

I have numbers such as this to round of “0.7823076923076923” using the code I have I can get it to round up to "1" but I need it to round to 0.78 I then added “toFixed(2)” and it takes my “1” and puts it to “1.00” but I need It to go to “0.78” once I have that in place I can then look at how I can loop the code, but small steps.

Thanks for all the help.

Code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').prop('id', 'test');
    $('#test').text(function(i,v) {
        return Math.round(parseInt(v * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    });
});
</script>
```

UPDATE
i got it working!!!

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').prop('id', 'test');
    var test = parseFloat($('#test').text()).toFixed(2);
    $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(5n)').empty().append(test);
});
```

now to make it loop,

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Answer (score 1):

To round a number to `n` decimal places:

```
var n = 2;
var number = 0.7823076923076923;
var result = Math.round(number * Math.pow(10,n)) / Math.pow(10,n);
result = result.toFixed(n);
```

---

*UPDATE:*

For a more reusable option, you can define a custom rounding function:

```
function roundTo (value, n) {
    var result = Math.round(value * Math.pow(10,n)) / Math.pow(10,n);
    return result.toFixed(n);
}

var foo = roundTo(0.7823076923076923, 2); // 0.78
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for this, 

How do i go about making var number dynamic rather than defining a number? like var number = #test or something im having no luck on this end doing this

Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing, you probably just want to make a new function in that case. Updated the answer.