# How can I get an input text to expand its digits to two if the user only enters one?

Tags: jquery, tofixed

I want to display values in text inputs that are in "dollar format"; IOW, instead of "10.5" I want it to be "10.50"

I was able to do that in the grand total box like so (last line of code):

```
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});
```

That working, I thought maybe I could get the individual "amount" boxes to work similarly by doing this (adding ".toFixed(2)" to their val()s):

```
var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val().toFixed(2)) : 0;
var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val().toFixed(2)) : 0;
. . .
```

It didn't; it fact, it broke the existing functionality.

So I then "dialed it back a bit" and tried on just the first "Amount" box like so:

```
$('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() == parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val().toFixed(2));
```

...but that also failed (entering "10.5" and exiting/blurring did not convert the "10.5" to "10.50" as I hoped).

How can I cause the inputs to always expand or contract to display two digits? IOW:

```
"10" should become "10.00"
"10.5" should become "10.50"
"10.567" should become "10.57"
```

etc.

Comment: Do you need safari to support your page?

Comment: I think your problem was already mentioned and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: Safari support would be nice, but not necessary.

Comment: `!= ''` is redundant since empty string is falsy anyway

Comment: @charlietfl: Is this some kind of involved wordplay about string bikinis?

Comment: ah yeah...  `(-) (-) === true`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() == parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val().toFixed(2));
```

… do this:

```
$('[id$=boxAmount1]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()).toFixed(2));
```

Note that the `toFixed()` method works with numbers only, so you need to apply it to the numeric result of `parseFloat()` instead of the string result of `val()`.

---

Your entire code can be reduced to the following:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.amountbox', function() {
  var grandtotal = 0;
  $('.amountbox').each(function() {
    var v= +$(this).val();
    if(v>'') {
      $(this).val(v.toFixed(2));
      grandtotal+= v;
    }
  });
  $('#boxGrandTotal').val(grandtotal.toFixed(2));
});
```

The jQuery **[`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** method saves you the trouble of looking at each input individually.

Prepending a plus sign (+) to a string coerces it to a number, so `parseFloat` isn't needed.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wqsb6vhL/4/)

Comment: additional tweak would be make sure result `!="NaN"`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to apply this to all the text inputs (without negatively impacting the others when they are blank), I had to spread the code into 5 handlers (in addition to the original one):

```
/* boxAmount1...boxAmount5 - when any of them change, update boxGrandTotal */
$(document).on("blur", '.amountbox', function (e) {
    var amount1 = $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()) : 0;
    var amount2 = $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()) : 0;
    var amount3 = $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()) : 0;
    var amount4 = $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()) : 0;
    var amount5 = $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val() != '' ? parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()) : 0;
    var grandtotal = amount1 + amount2 + amount3 + amount4 + amount5;
    $('[id$=boxGrandTotal]').val(parseFloat(grandtotal).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount1]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount1]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount1]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount2]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount2]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount2]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount3]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount3]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount3]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount4]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount4]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount4]').val()).toFixed(2));
});

$(document).on("blur", '[id$=boxAmount5]', function (e) {
    $('[id$=boxAmount5]').val(parseFloat($('[id$=boxAmount5]').val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Plugin time for Bonzo?