# Javascript to calculate input field values and show 2 decimal place accuracy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand this may be a repeat question but I have been searching for ages and cant figure out why this isnt working.

I have 3 input fields, Subtotal, Vat and Total: I want to be able to populate the VAT and Total inpur fields with values when there is a value inputted in Subtotal and to show 2 decimal palces after. So:

4 would be 4.00 
4.5 would be 4.50

HTML code for the input field:

```
<input name="subtotal" id="subtotal" type="number" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" onchange="vatCalculation();" />

<input name="vat" id="vat" type="number" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />

<input name="total" id="total" type="number" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />
```

And the javascript code I have at the moment is:

```
function vatCalculation() {
var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
var vat = parseFloat(parseFloat(subtotal) * parseFloat(0.2)).toFixed(2);
var total = parseFloat(parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(vat)).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById('vat').value = vat;
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

I cant see where I am going wrong. When I enter 10 in the 'subtotal'input field the 'VAT' and 'Total' fields change to 2 and 12. But I want them to show 2.00 and 12.00. Screenshot below:

[image]

SOLUTION:

When using Firefox the input field of type="number" dont seem to work with javascript calculation. Workaround is to change it to a type="text" Like J Santosh as mentioned below and it works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the issue . It is with `<input type='number'>`  you change it to `<input type='text'>`

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/pqgoateh/)

Input Type Number  is not accepting decimals

[Reference -1](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

[Reference-2](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number)

Comment: Perfect J Santosh... So annoying that it was something so small as that... Would you happen to know why it doesnt work when the type="number"?

Comment: @Harnamc it's because the browser automatically converts the value to a number, and displays it without the string format.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? If so, you were pretty close. You just needed to add

```
document.getElementById('subtotal').value = parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2);
```

to your code as well.

```js
function vatCalculation() {
var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal').value;
var vat = parseFloat(parseFloat(subtotal) * parseFloat(0.2)).toFixed(2);
var total = parseFloat(parseFloat(subtotal) + parseFloat(vat)).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById('subtotal').value = parseFloat(subtotal).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById('vat').value = vat;
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
```

```html
<input name="subtotal" id="subtotal" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" onchange="vatCalculation();" />

<input name="vat" id="vat" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />

<input name="total" id="total" type="text" maxlength="20" min="0" placeholder="00.00" readonly="true" />
```

Comment: Buzinas you are right, works fine in chrome but in Firefox it doesnt work when you use type="number"... going to use J Santosh's answer and change the input to type="text" and use RegEx to limit it to only numbers.

Comment: @mcon - it's working fine when you do type="text" in Firefox now. It was a browser issue. Thanks for your help to add extra decimal on the subtotal as well. Forgot about that :)

Answer (score 0):

`(2.399).toFixed(2);` will give you 2.40

But if you need 2.39  try

```
parseInt(2.399 * 100)/100
```