# Using Decimals in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a state as `value: 10.00` and once I update it with some operation and add it to a `<Text>` the ".00" part gets trimmed off. If it was a value like 10.50, it'll be displayed as 10.5

This is a issue as I want to display currency values. How to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Found the answer. To have the value with decimal values, use `toFixed()` method.

Example:

```
var value = 10;
value = value.toFixed(2);
this.setState({subTotal: value});
```

The output would be: 10.00

Comment: This will round your number to 2 decimal places. Depending on your use case it may be better to pass in a String instead of creating a String using toFixed.

Comment: or: this.setState({subTotal: value.toFixed(2)});   now your value will stay an number.

Comment: It is not working. it convert to string which is wrong for large calculations

Comment: The verified answer can return NaN if the user backspaces or adds a decimal into the Text Field before a number add the following to your function to prevent:  
`if (isNaN(value)) {return 0}`

Answer (score 8):

here is another solution you can also try, what i need is don't allow to enter more than 2 decimal digits (after decimal point) and also shouldn't allow  more than two decimal points or any other character.

```
    ConTwoDecDigit=(digit)=>{
      return digit.indexOf(".")>0?
              digit.split(".").length>=2?
               digit.split(".")[0]+"."+digit.split(".")[1].substring(-1,2)
              : digit
             : digit
    }
    <TextInput 
       value={this.state.salary}
       onChangeText={value => this.setState({ salary: this.ConTwoDecDigit(value) })} 
      keyboardType={'decimal-pad'}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the verified answer which catches more edge cases and allows string inputs. (defaults to 2dp but can be set by function caller)

```
export function normaliseValue (value: string, decimals = 2) {
  if (!value) {
    return ''
  }
  if (value === '.') {
    return value = '0.'
  }

  var regex = new RegExp(`^-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,${decimals}})?`)
  const decimalsNumber = value.toString().match(regex)[0]
  const parsed = parseFloat(decimalsNumber).toFixed(2)
  if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    return '0'
  }
  return parsed
}
```

Example use in code:

```
  <TextInput
    label='Hours worked'
    placeholder='Hours worked'
    keyboardType='decimal-pad'
    value={String(values.hours)}
    onChangeText={(val) => setFieldValue('hours', normaliseValue(val, 3))}
  />
```