# Adding 2 decimal places in textinput

Tags: react-native

i need help adding 2 decimal place in  after adding a value. for example if i add 100000 then it will convert it to 100,000.00 here is my current code.

```
<TextInput
            placeholder='0'
            keyboardType = 'decimal-pad'
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            style={{
            width:'90%',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight:'400'}}
            onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.onEnterText(TextInputValue)}
/>

onEnterText = (TextInputValue) =>{
     if(TextInputValue.trim() != 0){
      this.setState({TextInputValue : TextInputValue, ErrorStatus : true}) ;
    }else{
        this.setState({TextInputValue : TextInputValue, ErrorStatus : false}) ;
    }
  }
```

Comment: See if this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410655/using-decimals-in-react-native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
<TextInput
        placeholder='0'
        keyboardType = 'decimal-pad'
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        style={{
        width:'90%',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight:'400'}}
        onChangeText={TextInputValue => 
        this.onEnterText(TextInputValue % 1 == 0 ? TextInputValue+".00" : TextInputValue.toFixed(2))}
  />
```

The above code definitely works.
but I don't know what is inside your  `onEnterText()`

Comment: can you please tell me where should i copy this line in code? sorry for being noob. or can you paste a complete code

Comment: onChangeText={TextInputValue => this.onEnterText(TextInputValue % 1 == 0 ? TextInputValue+".00" : TextInputValue.toFixed(2))}

Comment: tried this but nothing happend

Comment: TypeError: TextInputValue.toFixed is not a function. (In 'TextInputValue.toFixed(2)', 'TextInputValue.toFixed' is undefined)

Comment: i tried and it didnt work.

Comment: i updated my code you can see onEnterText()  above.

Answer (score 0):

Try using toFixed(2) for variable approach.

For decimals in input you might find this link useful : https://codesandbox.io/s/9zjo1lp86w