# How to format data from table column with the same class using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have table row inside a foreach looping that are have some columns with the same class, my question is how can i format each data in that column to be like ###,### (format number using comma) in javascript?

this is a sample for my table structure:

```
    <tbody id="binder">
<?php foreach () { ?>        
        <tr id="data">
            <td class="sum">400000</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>

            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">500000</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
            <td class="sum">0</td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: you are wrong @Lulylulu

Comment: @Muhammad, you could look into `toLocaleString()` that means that it will format with comma for US but with spaces for France for example.

Comment: @Lulylulu, it is a different case. I mean how can i convert it manually creating any function to format all these data based on class='sum' in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the elements with the specific class name and then format its innerHTML. below is a working snippet.

```js
var allTds = document.getElementsByClassName("sum");

for (var i = 0; i < allTds.length; i++) {

  allTds[i].innerHTML = allTds[i].innerHTML.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

```css
td{
   border:1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="binder">
    <tr id="data">
      <td class="sum">400000</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>

      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">500000</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
      <td class="sum">0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The regex reference taken from this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/2592042

Comment: your code works like a charm! that is what i mean. thanks for your help bro... nice to see you here.

Comment: @MuhammadKhoirulUmam glad I could help you. Happy coding!!