# Subtracting 2 decimal numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, subtraction

Hi im trying to subtract 2 decimal numbers and it keeps returning some weird number.

```
var x = 0.00085022
var y = 0.00085050
var answer = x - y
alert(answer)
```

This is the number its returning  **-2.8000000000007186e-7**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Please have a look at here [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2012/03/displaying-numbers.html

Answer (score 3):

> The maximum number of decimals is 17, but floating point arithmetic is not always 100% accurate
>   http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp

Try this:

```
var x = 0.00085022 * 100000000;
var y = 0.00085050 * 100000000;
var answer = (x - y) / 100000000;
alert(answer);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that instead of dividing by `100000000` you can multiply by `0.000000001`, which is a less expensive calculation. But as always, for the sake of code clarity, this improvement should not be a concern until performance becomes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are subtracting with a higher number and the calculations are traversing to an even lower number. Yes -2.0 is lower and the decimal places precision is reaching exponentially higher.

If we round them up we get:

```
var x = 85022
var y = 85050
var answer = x - y
alert(answer); // = -28
```