# Print ".00" When The Result Is A Whole Number?

Tags: javascript

I want to try and print ".00" after the variables cache.todayHigh and cache.todayLow are whole numbers.

```
if (ddimgtooltip.showTips) {
  // update tooltip
  tip = 'High ' + strings.baro_info + ': ' + cache.todayHigh + ' ' + data.pressunit + ' ' + strings.at + ' ' + data.TpressTH +
  ' <br> ' + strings.minimum_info + ' ' + strings.baro_info + ': ' + cache.todayLow + ' ' + data.pressunit + ' ' + strings.at + ' ' + data.TpressTL;

  if (cache.trendVal !== -9999) {
    tip +=  '<br>' + strings.baro_trend_info + ': ' + baroTrend(cache.trendVal, data.pressunit, true) + ' ' +
    (cache.trendValRnd > 0 ? '' : '') + cache.trendValRnd + ' ' + data.pressunit + '/hr';
  }

  $('#imgtip5_txt').html(tip);
}
```

e.g. 1017 hPa to 1017.00 hPa.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

William

Comment: Please tag this as Javascript. Don't make readers decipher your code. The "variables" is effectively useless.

Comment: The post has been editied.

Comment: `if ( parseInt(numb, 10) === numb ) numb = numb + '.00'`

Comment: Thanks, adeneo. I presume "numb" is where the cache.todayHigh/Low are inserted?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'm struggling how I'm supposed to insert this into the code above? Is it as a seperate line, if statment or inside the original if statement?

Comment: @WilliamGrimsley , I updated answer , you need like this ?

Comment: Yes, potentially, though the value changes as this is part of my weather website, it's not one specific value. So, would I replace '1702 hPa' with something else?

Comment: @WilliamGrimsley now its hardcoded , you can dynamically change it with your own value

Comment: @WilliamGrimsley , you can put any value in yvalue

Comment: But, I don't change the value, the value comes from the weather station itself.

Comment: Show value format?

Comment: http://www.newton-poppleford-weather.co.uk/gauges.htm, hover over the pressure gauge and see the low pressure value is shown as a whole number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
var yvalue = '1702 hpa';
var num = yvalue.replace(/[^0-9]+/ig,"");
value = Number(num).toFixed(2);
var fvalue=  value +' '+yvalue.split(' ')[1]
console.log(fvalue);
```