# Round up the values in my calculator script & add commas separator for the value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the problem. My JS knowledge & experience is very poor so I can't solve it without your help. I have the following code for my simple calculator and I want to add some code for this:

If I enter a number such as 10010 into the calculator, I get $7.508 back. How can I make it so that there are always 2 digits past the period and round it up? In this case, it would be best if it showed $7.51 instead of $7.508. If I entered 4,000 it shows "$3" but can it say "$3.00"? 
Thank you in advance!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>

<script type="text/javascript">function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 10000){
        return 0.00099;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.00095;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.00089;
    }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
        return 0.00075;
    }else{
        return 0.00075;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
    var total = inputVal * price;
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text(numFormat.format(total)); // display the total price
});

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `total` to be 2 decimal places by adding `total.toFixed(2)`. I have added it for you.

`var total = (inputVal * price).toFixed(2);` Read more about [.toFixed at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Check it out in the **DEMO** below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>

<script type="text/javascript">function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 10000){
        return 0.00099;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.00095;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.00089;
    }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
        return 0.00075;
    }else{
        return 0.00075;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
    var total = (inputVal * price);
    total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text((total)); // display the total price
});

</script>
```

Comment: It works great for me! The rounding up part is absolutely perfect. Could you, please, help me with my second issue in this post? If I entered 4,000 it shows "$3" but can it say "$3.00"?

Comment: Okay, let me check it out.

Comment: According to your `priceCalculation` function, `4000` becomes `0.00099`, and `total` becomes `0.00099 * 4000 = 3.96`.

Comment: Ok but If I entered 40,000 it shows "$30" but how can it say "$30.00" ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Try the demo again, I have modified it. I added this `total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`

Comment: It works great, my friend! Thank you so much for your help and solution!

Answer (score 1):

[`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) accepts an options parameter that allows you to influence style.

From your example, it seems like you could use:

```
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' });
```

Note that this will also add the currency symbol (such as here, a dollar sign). If you really just want to control the rounding, you may set `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits` instead:

```
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'decimal', minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Important line :

```
    var total = (inputVal * price).toFixed(2);
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wd12w4t6/6/)

Try below code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="How many likes?" style="height: 50px;width: 360px;color: #222;border-radius: 5px;border: 1px #85c9e3 solid;font-size: 18px;" type="text" id="likecount" />
<p style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; padding: 20px 0px; font-weight: bold; color: #222; ">Pricing: <b><span style="color: #004f04;"> $</span><span id="output" style="color: #004f04;"></span></b></p>

<script type="text/javascript">function priceCalculation(a){
    if(a <= 10000){
        return 0.00099;
    }else if(a >= 10001 && a <= 25000 ){
        return 0.00095;
    }else if(a >= 25001 && a <= 50000 ){
        return 0.00089;
    }else if(a >= 50001 && a <= 100000 ){
        return 0.00075;
    }else{
        return 0.00075;
    }
}

// number format set to en-US e.g (from 1500 to 1,500)
var numFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US");

$('#likecount').keyup(function(e){
    // if a '.' is pressed
 if($(this).val().endsWith('.')) {
     return;
    }

    // if input value is empty then assign '0' else the original value
    var inputVal = $(this).val() === ''?'0':$(this).val();
  
    inputVal = parseFloat(inputVal.replace(/[$|,]/g, ''));
    var price = priceCalculation($(this).val());
    var total = (inputVal * price);
    total = (Math.round(total * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    var formatted = numFormat.format(inputVal) // set format to input
    $(this).val(formatted); // display the formatted input back
    $('#output').text(total); // display the total price
});

</script>
```

Comment: @Morgari, as per calculation, 4000 becomes $3.96. and your code does not show $3.

Comment: It works great for me! The rounding up part is absolutely perfect.  But for the second post part If I entered 40,000 it shows "$30" but can it say "$30.00"?

Comment: Unfortunately the pricing value is still 30 (note 30.00)