# How to format comma separated value to two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I convert the comma separated value with some decimal value round off to two places.

```
Example:
var number = '4,500.02734'
output: 4, 500.03
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: use `.toFixed(2)`

Comment: I agree with @guradio. Use `var n = 4.005` and `n.toFixed(2)` would round to nearest hundredth.

Comment: yes toFixed can convert number without comma. But I am asking for number with comma.

Comment: `(+number.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '')).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @Samuel, i dont think my question is duplicate. I am asking about the comma separated number as amount figure with decimal value

Comment: @Phil But your solution remove ',' from my number

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This requires two operations...

1. Parse the number string into a `Number` instance

   ```
   const actualNumber = +number.replace(/,/g, '') // produces 4500.02734
   ```
2. Format the string to a given locale with a maximum of 2 decimal places

   ```
   const formatted = actualNumber.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2})
   ```

```js
var number = '4,500.02734'

const actualNumber = +number.replace(/,/g, '')
const formatted = actualNumber.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits: 2})

document.write(formatted)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this simple function that will convert your number to comma separated value and decimal number round off as well.

```js
var number = 5000000.245;
document.write(format_number(number));

function format_number(n) {
  return n.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function format(a) {
    var i=a.indexOf(".");
    var f=(parseFloat("0"+a.substring(i)).toFixed(2)).toString();
    return a.substring(0,i)+"."+f.substring(2,f.length);
}
```

`format("4,500.02734")` outputs `4,500.03`.

Comment: Thank you very much