# Calculate total in dynamic form - Ant Design React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a dynamic form in Ant Design where I can:

- set the price and the quantity in some inputs.
- create new rows

I was able to access all the values from the rows after submiting with this piece of code:

```
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };
```

But I would like to access each value from the inputs, get the total (price * quantity) and set it the total input.

[image]

I saw a solution in basic React from this question [Calculating quantity and price total in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793118/calculating-quantity-and-price-total-in-react). That answer shows that you need use state and use the onChange event and work from there, but I don't really know how to translate this answer because I don't understand how to access the state from each row in Ant Design.

You can see my code right here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-hawking-pcr7k?file=/index.js:260-348

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate derived values by taking advantage of the `onValuesChange` event handler on the `Form` component, and the `form` instance methods provided by the `Form.useForm` hook.

Please see sandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/antdesign-calculating-a-derived-value-using-dynamic-form-hgyzh?file=/index.js:229-1020

```js
const ItemForm = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm()
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log('Received values of form:', values)
  }

  const handleTotal = (_, values) => {
    const rowsCopy = [...values.rows]
    values.rows.forEach((fieldGroup, index) => {
      if (fieldGroup && fieldGroup.quantity && fieldGroup.price) {
        fieldGroup.total = fieldGroup.quantity * fieldGroup.price
        rowsCopy.splice(index, 1, fieldGroup)
        console.log('fieldGroup', fieldGroup)
        console.log('rowsCopy', rowsCopy)
        form.setFieldsValue({ rows: rowsCopy })
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <Form
      name="dynamic_form_nest_item"
      form={form}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onValuesChange={handleTotal}
      autoComplete="off"
      size="small"
    >
```

Comment: thanks, what is the first parameter of handleTotal `_`? and why do you need to copy the rows in this part `rowsCopy.splice(index, 1, fieldGroup)`?

Comment: The first parameter is `changedValues`, basically only the last value that was changed on the form. As for `rowsCopy` that is just for convenience, the splice step is replacing the edited form group {count: XX, price: XX, total: undefined} with {count: XX, price: XX, total: CALCULATED_TOTAL}.