# number_format() in php vs toFixed() in jQuery for validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation, number-formatting, tofixed

I am having some data calculation on my client side, which I want to validate on the server end. Let's say my calculated value result is `34.55`

`(34.55).toFixed(1)` gives me `34.5`

Strangely, `(34.555).toFixed(1)` gives me `34.6`

`number_format(34.55, 1, '.', '')` gives me `34.6`

Can anyone suggest me an exact equivalent of either of the functions?

Comment: I got the workaround for this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134070/3259671

Answer (score 1):

```
round(1.95583, 2);  // 1.96

round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //  1.5

round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //  1.5

round( 1.55, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //  1.6

round( 1.54, 1, PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN); //  1.5
```

if you have any questions, ask

Comment: toFixed() is giving me inconsistent results.
`555x0.029 = 16.095 --> (16.095).toFixed(2) returns 16.10`

`5555x0.029 = 161.095 --> (161.095).toFixed(2) returns 161.09`