# Formatting numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am needing format a data with 8 decimal numbers, eg:

**843332**     -> **0.00843332** 
**123456789**  -> **1.23456789** 
**9876543210** -> **98.76543210**

How could I perform this task in JavaScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1):

Just divide by `1e8`:

```js
const translate = num => num / 1e8;
console.log(
  [
    843332,
    123456789,
    9876543210
  ]
    .map(translate)
);
```

Comment: These numbers still need a `.toFixed(8)`.

Comment: If OP needs a string, yes, but that wasn't specified

Comment: The desired output for the last sample is `98.76543210` instead of `98.7654321` which implies `toFixed` to be used, and thus a string.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
 var value = ["843332", "123456789", "9876543210"];
    
    for(i =0; i < value.length; i++){
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (value[i] /100000000).toFixed(8) + " <br />";
    }
    
}
```

```html
<p>Click button to generate</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Please try this.

```
function myFunction() {
 var value = ["843332", "123456789", "9876543210"];

 for(i =0; i < value.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (value[i]/100000000).toFixed(8) + " <br />";
 }
}
```