# Number value format with comma and two decimal points

Tags: javascript, chart.js, number-formatting

I am using chart.js to display my sales the problem is I cannot convert the data into a number format with comma and two decimal places properly.

When the data is a whole number the output is correct. However, when I display the average sales I am getting a output like

> Average Sales (no format) 1000.2017
>   Average Sales (with format) 1,000.2,017
>   Total Sales (no format) 1000
>   Total Sales (with format) 1,000

How can format the out put correctly in javascript?

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
     label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
         var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
         value = value.toString();
         value = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              return value;
           }
       }
  },
   scales: {
     yAxes: [{
       ticks: {
         userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
           value = value.toString();
           value = value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              return value;
         }
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Is '1000.2017' one number or two?

Comment: Is 'Average Sales (with format) 1,000.2,017' actually what you want? That's not a valid number format.

Comment: no that is the output of my code I want to fix the format

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Javascript offers you few solutions to do that. First two coming to mind below.

**1. number.toLocaleString**

As already mentioned, .toLocaleString can help you, but instead of `minimumFractionDigits` use `maximumFractionDigits`.

Like below:

```
number.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
```

So summarizing:

```
const decimalsFormated = number.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 2 })
```

And than

```
const finalFormated = String(decimalsFormated).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

**2. Number.parseFloat + toFixed**

```
let number = 123.1234
Number.parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
```

In each approach, wrap your solution in function preferably:

```
function getCommaSeparatedTwoDecimalsNumber(number) {
    const fixedNumber = Number.parseFloat(number).toFixed(2);
    return String(fixedNumber).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

}
```

You could also use regex. I would say it is overaly complicated though.

Also **very important thing** to notice is that you may or may not want to round your final outcome.

Using `toLocaleString` with maxDigits will just remove everything after those two digits. 
Using `toFixed` will round your output unproperly.

This solution will round it properly:

```
Number(Math.round(1.005+'e2')+'e-2').toFixed(2);
```

Pasted from here:
[Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Last thing, probably most important. 
Depending on what format input number will have, above solution may or may not work. You need to decide on input format and if that cant be foreseen, provide formaters for each possibility:

1000000.123124

10000123123

100000,1239

1.12039

1,19012

etc.

And depending on format, order of actions you need to take may vary.

Comment: Number.parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).replace(/[.]/, ",")); is working but there is no comma I need to have a comma and decimal point like **1,000.00**

Comment: Just to be clear the output of Number.parseFloat(number).toFixed(2).replace(/[.]/, ",")); is **1000.00** what I need is **1,000.00**

Comment: Actually it s not, cause `.replace(/[.]/, ","));` will replace dot with comma. I misunderstood you at the beginning. Is my answer OK now?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using toLocaleString like this:

```
value = value.toLocaleString(undefined, { maximumFractionDigits: 2 });
```

It will format the number according to your locale with thousand separators and 2 digits after comma.

Comment: What browser are you using, not all browsers support toLocaleString with parameters (Edge does).

Comment: I am using chrome

Comment: it wont work, cause `minimum` should be replaced with `maximum` in this answer

Comment: please upvote my comment and/or answer since it helped :)

Comment: All these answers do not work if the value has only 1 decimal place. e.g. 1.1. output should be 1.10

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for:

- Commas
- 2 decimal points no matter the number.

Here is your function:

```js
function get4DecimalPointsWithCommas(amount) {
  return amount.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    maximumFractionDigits: 4,
    minimumFractionDigits: 4
  });
}
console.log(get4DecimalPointsWithCommas(33))
```