# Adding a formula to calculate a price onkeyup from values via inputBox

Tags: javascript

I've got a pricing page with two plans. On the first [pricing plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iExAs.png), I'm adding a feature where a user can type in a value and a price for that value will return on the right-hand side (onkeyup). See how it works [here](https://carryr.webflow.io/pricing). This is the code that has already been implemented:

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('orderValue');

inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  document.getElementById('deliveryPrice').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
```

I need to add a formula to the output value, `(value * 0.025) + 4`. Then I would need to format everything as a currency (`£000,000.000`) onkeyup too and output value. Can anyone help?

Comment: Break this down in to steps. The formula can be written exactly as you have it in the question. To format a value to 2 decimal places see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134070/519413),  and to add the `,` to group the number in thousands, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/519413)

Comment: Here you can see some [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255239/4071759).

Comment: I posted the answe. hope you will get what you are looking for. do give thums up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elDeliveryPrice = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
var elOrderValue = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' });

elOrderValue.addEventListener('keyup', _ => {
    let curVal = elOrderValue.value; 

    let curValFloat = parseFloat(curVal);
    if (isNaN(curValFloat)) {
        elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }

    elDeliveryPrice.innerHTML = formatter.format((curValFloat * 0.025) + 4);
});
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I also need the inputBox to display the same currency formatting on keyup too - have an idea how to include it?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the result of your formula in a new variable and then use `toLocaleString()` to convert your new number into a string which is comma separated. Lastly you can use the HTML entity `&pound;` as a prefix to your new value to add the pounds symbol.

See working example below:

```js
var inputBox = document.getElementById('orderValue');
var outputElem = document.getElementById('deliveryPrice');
inputBox.onkeyup = function() {
  var newValue = this.value * 0.025 + 4;
  outputElem.innerHTML = "&pound;" + newValue.toLocaleString();;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="orderValue" />
<span id="deliveryPrice"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to add space after every 3 characters and add £ to add the currency symbol

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('orderValue');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
  var val = (Number(inputBox.value)* 0.025) + 4;
  val = val.toFixed(3).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, ' ')
  document.getElementById('deliveryPrice').innerHTML = "&pound; "+val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]here is the complete working code. See Sacreenshot http://prntscr.com/mazqw1

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('orderValue');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
var x=parseFloat(Math.round(((inputBox.value* 0.025) + 4) * 100) / 100).toFixed(3);
var x=x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
document.getElementById('deliveryPrice').innerHTML =x;
}
```