# TypeScript Equivalent

Tags: angular, typescript, precision

Using the below code in Angular to cast the number to 2 decimal places using `DecimalPipe`.

```
constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

this.decimalPipe.transform('0','.2-2') //output 0.00
```

Any ideas of the`TypeScript` equivalent?

`toPrecision(2)` doesn't works the same

e.g.

```
var num = 2;

2.toPrecision(2)
```

Expected: `2.00`
Actual: `2.0`

Comment: can copy: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/i18n/format_number.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript function `toFixed(2);`

If you want to round, you can use `(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);`

Refer more at https://stackoverflow.com/a/6134070/4964569

Comment: I need a different output, could you please check my update?

Comment: var a = 2; a.toFixed(2) return your expectation 2.00

Comment: Why do you need to use Math.round? `toFixed` rounds a value by default. `(1.999).toFixed(2) // 2.00`