# Change Output to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS file. This snippet will display Delivery Charge but its in 4 decimal places. I want it to display only two decimal places. How to change the code?

```js
if (val.order_id > 0) {
  html += '<div class="col text-right">';
  html += "<b class='amout'>" + val.order_total_amount + "</b>";
  html += "<b class='charge_thaitop " + val.payment_type_raw + "'>" + getTrans('Delivery Fee ', 'deliver_fee') + getTrans('RM', 'MYR') + val.delivery_charge + "</b>";
  html += '</div>';
}
```

The + val.delivery_charge+ will output the number but currently its in 4 decimal places. I want it in two decimal places only. Refer the output in the picture below:

[output in red rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGd3I.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: use `toFixed(2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Please check if question already exists :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a string and count below the comma and check if ther are more or less than 2 chars.

Or method `.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solutions.

Sorry im not familiar with this JS.

But i put **prettyPrice(val.delivery_charge)** and its worked.

Thanks for the suggestion