# How to store number with thousand separator in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to store an Array like this

```
const price = [ 1.000, 24.500, 3.99, 4.00 ];
```

but when i'm print this with console.log, the 1.000 becomes 1 , the 4.00 become 4.

how to keep the thousand number with dot separator?

Comment: `.` is decimal point, not thousands separator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: Seconding @kmoser 's assertion and recommending this be closed as a duplicate of that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

`console.log(price.toFixed(3));`

#### edit-1:

```js
prices.forEach((price)=>{ console.log(price.toFixed(3)); })

let truePrice = prices.map( (price)=> price.toFixed(3) )
```

Comment: it works, thanks.
`let truePrice  = prices.forEach((price)=>{
     console.log(price.toFixed(3));
})`