# JavaScript limit output decimal places

Tags: javascript, json, function, api, decimal

I've been trying to limit the output data for 'priceChangePercent' to 2 decimal places but can't seem to get it working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Function**

```js
async function getPriceBTCUSDT() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT");
  const data = await response.json();
  const {
    prevClosePrice,
    priceChangePercent
  } = data;
  if (priceChangePercent > 0) {
    document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').style.color = 'green'
  }

  document.getElementById('price-btcusdt').textContent = prevClosePrice;
  document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt').textContent = priceChangePercent + "%";

}

getPriceBTCUSDT();

setInterval(getPriceBTCUSDT, 3000);
```

```html
<span id="price-btcusdt"></span>
<span id="24hr-btcusdt"></span>
```

Comment: var num = 5.56789;  var n = num.toFixed(2);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toFixed(2) will do the trick after you cast to number

You may want to add the currency too?

I added colour classes too.

```js
async function getPriceBTCUSDT() {
  const response = await fetch("https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCUSDT");
  const data = await response.json();
  const {
    prevClosePrice,
    priceChangePercent
  } = data; 
  const pctSpan = document.getElementById('24hr-btcusdt');
  const priceSpan = document.getElementById('price-btcusdt');
  pctSpan.className = priceChangePercent >= 0 ? "green" : "red";
  pctSpan.textContent = priceChangePercent + "%";
  priceSpan.textContent = "$" + Number(prevClosePrice).toFixed(2);
  

}

getPriceBTCUSDT();

setInterval(getPriceBTCUSDT, 3000);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<span id="price-btcusdt"></span>
<span id="24hr-btcusdt"></span>
```