# Why node truncate automatically double?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Hi why if I create a variable in my backend:

```
var price = 10.10;
```

When I render la page the var is truncate to 10.1?

```
<span class="form-group-field">Price: € <%=price%></span><br>
<input type="hidden" id="price" name="price" value="<%=price%>"/>
```

Comment: JavaScript does not keep formatting for the numbers. If you need to represent a number in a specific way, use a string.

Comment: You're asking *why* it happens but if you actually want to know *how to change it*, then: [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6134039)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use toFixed method as javascript removes the 0's after the decimal

```
 var price = 10.10

 price.toFixed(2)  //it will result 10.10
```