# JavaScript integer with 0 value decimal

Tags: javascript

Possible duplicate of a similar question so sorry about that.

However, I can't seem to figure it out whether it is possible to print an integer with 0 value decimal. I have checked the https://javascript.info/number documentation still can't find an answer.

My attemps:

```js
const sum = 1.0 + 1.0
const e = sum.toFixed(1)

console.log(e)
// string output "2.0"
```

```js
const sum= 1.0 + 1.0
const e =+sum.toFixed(1)

console.log(e)
// integer output with no decimal 2
```

```js
const sum= 1.0 + 1.0
const e = Number(sum.toFixed(1))

console.log(e)
// same integer output with no decimal 2
```

Is it possible to print an integer with a value of 2.0?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: What's wrong with your first snippet? That's how it should be done.

Comment: `2.0` is not an integer ... Numbers in JS are presented according to [IEEE 754 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), leading and trailing zeros are not included.

Comment: I guess this answers my questions. Thanks Teemu  !!!

Comment: @sp00m The first snippet doesn't return an integer .https://jsbin.com/zihahunonu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: @AdeN You can't return `2.0` as an integer, that's not how JS represents integers. A string/float are the only ways you can display it like that (And a float will probably not show the decimal if it's `.0`) If it's for display purposes, it shouldn't mater that it's a string, and if it's for use in calculations, the format shouldn't matter. I'm having trouble understanding the problem here.

Comment: @DBS thanks for the comment. I was trying to solve this problem using JavaScript https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-data-types/problem . I guess Java is better equipped to deal with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your answer :

```
const sum= 1.0 + 1.0
const e = Number(sum.toFixed(1))
console.log(Number(e).toFixed(1))
```

Comment: Why would you convert number to a string (`toFixed`), then back to a number (`Number()`), then try and convert number-number again... then back to string? The only difference between this and the asker's first snippet is a lot of unnecessary type conversion.

Comment: Using typeof before the logged value tells its a string, not Number.