# How to add zeroes in the end of the values of two const which are defined with js

Tags: javascript

I have a working code which define two const with js and then multiply those two const to get third value. But what I need is to add zeroes in the end of the values and I need help with that:

```
<p> Total odd:  <span id = "totaleur_id"> </span> </p>
<p> Stake:      <span id = "steur_id">    </span> </p>
<p> Return:     <span id = "posseur_id">  </span> </p>


<script>
const totaleur = 1.80
const steur = 50
const possibleWinnings = totaleur * steur
document.querySelector("#totaleur_id").textContent = totaleur;
document.querySelector("#steur_id").textContent = steur;
document.querySelector("#posseur_id").textContent = possibleWinnings;
</script>
```

What I get as an frontend result is:

```
Total odd: 1.8
Stake:    50
Return:   90
```

But I need the result to be:

```
Total odd: 1.80
Stake:    50
Return:   90.00
```

And other frontend result example:

```
Total odd: 2.35
Stake:     50
Return:    117.5 //this should be: 117.50
```

Comment: Hi! You can use the `toFixed` method: `totaleur.toFixed(2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `toFixed` method passing as input the number of numbers you want after the comma:

```
const possibleWinnings = (totaleur * steur).toFixed(2)
```