# how to convert 4 decimal string to 2 decimal string in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm getting value like this.

```
data[0].percentage='0.0000'
```

I want this value as =

> '0.00'

how to convert

> '0.0000' to '0.00'

i tried

```
parseFloat(data[0].percentage).toFixed(2)
```

im getting NaN

Comment: Should it be rounded, or just *trimmed*?

Comment: it should be rounded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Your code works as posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const percentage = '0.0000';
console.log(Number(percentage).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: thanks. its working fine for me

Comment: To be fair, the code in the OP also works just fine.

Comment: agreed. That was added after my answer, fyi.