# Typescript returns string on operation number.tofixed & parseFloat doesn't return double as datatype always

Tags: javascript, typescript, loopback4, parsefloat, tofixed

```
const number = 100
```

number.toFixed(2) -> "100.00"

```
parseFloat(number.toFixed(2))  -> 100
```

I am not getting expected result as 100.00 as double type
if input is 100.36 getting expected result

Framework - loopback4

Comment: well, why would parseFloat include the zeros, they don't change the number

Comment: The answer you have been looking might be in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: `parseFloat()` is doing what it's suppose to do, 100.00 is same as 100 and both are float, `parseFloat()` just simplifies it.

If you want it to return 100.00 then you can use string value which is returned by `number.toFixed(2)`

Now I don't know what exactly you're trying to accomplish here but for calculations `parseFloat()` will work fine, but if you want to **display** it then use string instead.

Comment: is there a way to return 100 to 100.00 as double type by keeping in mind i cant use string the return i need is type double so?

Answer (score 1):

Is that solution what you are looking for?

```js
const number = 100.3611
let newNumber = parseFloat(number).toFixed(2)

console.log(newNumber)
```