# How to format the number? I was looking for the answer but haven't been able find the right one

Tags: javascript

So I have following numbers and I would like to format it in the following way

- 450.03,999,999 -> 450.03
- 2,597.6,099,999 -> 2,597.60
- 69.2 -> 69.20
- 100,780.090,100 -> 100,780.09

Could you assist with this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you don't typically put commas after the decimal point.

Comment: I know that, but thats what I get from API. I have no choice but format the number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I saw this solution as well, but no success

Comment: what is the data type in API? I believe in string formate, right? as those are not valid numbers.

Comment: it says number when i check typeof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get it done this way. I hope it would work for you.

```
let value = "2,597.6,099,999";
let num = Number(value.replace(/,/g, ""));
let result = num.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 2})
```