# Angular removes trailing zero from float

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am using spring boot and angular in which angular is removing trailing zero from a float data type object coming from the response.

For example, angular changes 10.00 to 10. However, using postman I can clearly see that the value is fine in postman that is 10.00

Please suggest some fix / solution in this case.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places

Comment: @Vojtone thanks for the reply. but this is not the response I wanted to know.
I request you to kindly re-read my question please.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `10` and `10.00` be that same value.

I don't know what is your core issue about the decimal place, but for display the value is can be simple like

**Angular (Js, Ts)**

```
<span> {{ data | number: '1.2-2' }} </span>
```

**Spring boot (JAVA)**

```
System.out.printf("%.2f", val);
```

Comment: @paranaan thanks for the reply. But, i cannot use pipe beacuse I am talking about json object not html element.

Comment: Why not, inject `DecimalPipe` in to your component and use like `this.decimalPipe.transform(num, '1.2-2');`

Comment: I appreciate the response. But, I am getting a proper value from spring boot rest api but the thing is that angular is changing the value from float to int if it is ending with 00 or 0