# Is there any C# String.Format() equivalent function in Javascript for formatting decimal values?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using c# string.Format(format,value) function but I want to achieve this in javascript which I would like to give me the same result which c# give me.
Below is the example in c# :

string.Format (62.505152, {0:0.0})
this will return me 62.5

string.Format (62.505152, {0:0.00})
this will return me 62.51

string.Format (62.505152, {0:0.1%})
this will return me 62511%

How can I achieve above examples in javascript which should give me the same return results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)