# Show 2 digits before decimal and show 3 digits after decimal point

Tags: javascript, node.js, decimal

The number is a single digit or whatever its, I want the value as before 2 digit and after 3 digits in decimal value.

```
Received values:
7, 
07, 
07.1, 
07.10, 
17.222,
```

Expected output:

07.000,
07.000,
07.100,
07.100,
17.222

Comment: duplicates: [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros) and [Format number to always show 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134039/format-number-to-always-show-2-decimal-places)

Comment: function f_(n){
 
 n = n ? n.split('.') : [];

 if( !n[0] ){ n[0] = '00'; }
 if( !n[1] ){ n[1] = '000'; }
 for(let a=1; a>-1; a--){ if( !n[0][a] ){ n[0] = '0'+n[0]; } }
 for(let a=0; a<3; a++){ if( !n[1][a] ){ n[1] += '0'; } }
 return n.join('.');
}

for(let x of ['','7', '07', '07.1', '07.10', '17.222']){
 console.log( f_(x) )
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function formatNumber(number) {
  return number.toFixed(3).padStart(6, '0');
}
```

Does this do the trick for you  ?

Comment: don't answer obvious duplicates, flag to close  (I didn't downvote, but code only answers are frowned upon)

Comment: But if i use this number e.g 07.1 , it's not working formatNumber(07.1)

Comment: @Muthukumar it is because of the 0 in front. Add a step in function that remove the 0 in front when there is one

Comment: @Johan if I used this method, ->  Number(number).toFixed(3).padStart(6, '0'). It works well.

Comment: @Muthukumar great ! :)